# What is the small cylinder on the firewall to the left of the battery?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, feature-identification, cessna-150

What is this and should the yellow wire be soldered to it?

Any ideas on preventing the wire from detaching again?

[image: small cylinder with black knob on top attached to firewall to left of battery]

I checked the C150 parts manual but didn't see it. Is there somewhere else I should be looking, or did I just miss it?

Comment: Are you working on this airplane yourself? If so you need to be aware of your local regulations.

Comment: Whats under door #1? that looks like it could be a cable connection cap, could be an antenna connector. Showing us whats under the cap could be of big help.

Comment: @GdD: I'm not modifying anything without supervision from an A&P, I'm just curious about what goes on with my plane and prefer to post here where the answers can potentially help others.

Comment: @Zaz: Freehand red circle might be usefull to save time getting what you mean. :P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That is a fuseholder for the optional clock or optional Hobbs meter. The yellow wire probably should be connected to it but you should have a certified mechanic inspect it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Interesting to see the free wire maybe the one directly and permanently connected to the battery anode.

Comment: Thank you! Where did you find this? I couldn't find it in the 1965 POH or parts manual.

Comment: I recognised it as a fuseholder and had a hunch it would be for a Hobbs meter. I then did a Google search and found multiple references.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I have a couple of questions: My plane has a wind-up clock and no Hobbs; also, there's no voltage between the wire and the cathode *or* anode. What does this mean? Could it be the generator fuse that is no longer used now the plane has an STC alternator?